# string subscripting of arrays

Tags: arrays, vb.net, field

In the many examples of reading MySQL data into VB code, the syntax of retrieving an element is of the form of arrays with strings as subscripts.  The strings are, in fact, the field names of the columns in the read DB Table.  For example:

```
datarow = sqlcmdRmScores.ExecuteReader()
datatable.Load(datarow)
```

followed by

```
For Each row As DataRow In datatable.Rows
    variable = row.Field(Of String)("RR_DE_PK1")
```

I'd like to define and reference regularly declared array elements using non-numeric indexes.  OK, I do it a lot in PHP.  Am I just spoiled?

Comment: What do you mean by "define and reference regularly declared array elements using non-numeric indexes"? What is it that PHP does that you'd like to do in VB.NET?

Answer (score 0):

`DataTables` are an alternative to `Array`s, and can be used without any actual database. A huge advantage over standard arrays is that you can mix data types:

```
Dim MyDataTable As New DataTable
MyDataTable.Columns.Add("ColumnName1", GetType(String))
MyDataTable.Columns.Add("ColumnName2", GetType(Integer))
MyDataTable.Rows.Add("Row0Col1", 0)
MyDataTable.Rows.Add("Row1Col1", 1)
Console.WriteLine(MyDataTable.Rows(1)("ColumnName1"))
```